# Plot is changing its size if I display a picture

Tags: python, matplotlib, rectangles

I need a little help with my code.
I want to use a picture as a background.
The picture will be a measurement device so I can visualize at which position the device has which velocity.
Unfortunately whenever I activate line 47:

```
ax3.imshow(img, extent=[x1, x3, 0, max(ID2)])
```

The third plot is changing its size after selecting an area with the rectangle selector.
Whithout line 47 is it working fine.
Do you have an idea what the problem is?

Plot 1 and 2:
x-axis: the travelled way
y-axis: velocity

plot 3:
x-axis: the travelled way
y-axis: Wt (the device is travveling in a pipeline. The top and bottom line are the diameter for the pipeline.)

Additional this is my picture.
(At the moment it is just a red background made from paint as a placeholder and i can see if the code is working.)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkbuH.png)

I have one more questions that you might can answer:
Is it possible that the rectangle stays at the maximum y-axis size.
This means that i can only move him to the right and to the left and not up and down anymore.

I hope I wrote it clear enough.
Please let me know if you have any questions.

Thank you and best regards

```
from matplotlib.widgets import RectangleSelector
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


'''Daten einlesen'''

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y = [1,1,2,1,0,0,1,3,5,1]
ID1 = [5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]
ID2 = [200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200]

img = plt.imread("bild.png")

'''PLotten'''

plt.close()

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3)


def Daten_plotten (ax, xx, yy):
    ax.plot(xx,yy)
    ax.set_xlim([min(xx)-1, max(xx)+1])
    ax.set_ylim([min(yy)-0.5, max(yy)+0.5])

Daten_plotten(ax1,x,y,)
Daten_plotten(ax2,x,y)
Daten_plotten(ax3,x,ID1)
Daten_plotten(ax3,x,ID2)
ax3.set_xlim([min(x), max(x)])
ax3.set_ylim([0,max(ID2)+1])


def line_select_callback_ax1(eclick, erelease):
    'eclick and erelease are the press and release events'
    x1, y1 = eclick.xdata, min(y)-0.5
    x2, y2 = erelease.xdata, max(y)+0.5
    x3 = x1 + (x2-x1)/2
    
    print("(%3.2f) --> (%3.2f)" % (x1, x2))
    print(x3)
                  
    ax2.set_xlim([x1, x2])
    ax2.set_ylim([y1, y2])
    
    
    ax3.imshow(img, extent=[x1, x3, 0, max(ID2)])
   
    ax3.set_xlim([x1, x2])
    ax3.set_ylim([0, max(ID2)+1])
    
    plt.pause(0.01)
    fig.canvas.draw

RS = RectangleSelector(ax1, line_select_callback_ax1,
                                       drawtype='box', useblit=True,
                                       button=[1, 3],  # don't use middle button
                                       minspanx=1, minspany=1,
                                       spancoords='pixels',
                                       interactive=True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: By default, `imshow` sets the data aspect ratio to 1:1, so when you select an area it changes the size of the axes to match the aspect ratio of the data range you selected.  You can set `aspect='auto'` instead if you want the axes to stay the same size.

Comment: That works.Thank you.